# Passing char * parameter to C++ dll function from C# GUI

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, dllimport

I have a cpp function as DLL file to read a file from certain file path and gives back "0" if success and other number if something failed:

```
short __stdcall ReadPx(char *filePath, MAP *map, int *num);
```

This function is defined in my C# as:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadPx", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern System.Int16 ReadPx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filePath, ref MAP Map, ref Int32 numE);
```

And it is called in the main function as:

```
var pix = new MAP();
int num = 1;
string path = "C:/Users/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/testWrapper2/Map\0";
System.Int16 Output = ReadPx(path, ref pix, ref num);
Console.WriteLine(Output);
```

The function runs fine but gives an invalid file path error. I think the problem might be that in the C# code defines “String filePath” as Unicode (2 bytes per character), whereas the ReadPx expects a pointer to a simple ASCII string. That is why I tried some modifications shown below, but the file path error still there.

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadPx", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern System.Int16 ScReadPixMap(IntPtr filePath, ref PIXMAPENTRY pixMap, ref Int32 numEntries);

IntPtr ptrCString = (IntPtr)Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(path);
System.Int16 output = ReadPx(ptrCString, ref pix, ref num);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrCString);
```

Some thoughts and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: when you debug your code, what does the parameter `filePath` hold?

Comment: You are using the wrong calling convention.  If you have c++ interface you must use CDecl not StdCall which is a windows calling convention

Comment: The original version passes the string correctly. Something else is wrong. Do some debugging.

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow when I debug, the `filepath` contains the complete path.

Comment: @fins and does it not show any weird characters? So maybe it's not the encodng

Comment: @jdweng If I used CDecl, there will be an error said that the function cannot be found in the dll library.

Comment: @fin why are you using a backslash here `testWrapper2/Map\0` ?

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow the `filepath` parameter expect a pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the file name to open

Comment: put the dll into the project bin folder where the exe get built.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I did.

Comment: @jdweng No, it's fine to use `__stdcall`, your comments here are actually confusing the asker and making matters worse. It would be best if you retracted them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ declaration is:

```
short __stdcall ReadPx(char *filePath, MAP *map, int *num);
```

Your C# declaration is:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint = "ReadPx", 
    CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern System.Int16 ReadPx(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filePath, 
    ref MAP Map, 
    ref Int32 numE
);
```

Given the information that we have available, there are no mistakes in this. Note however that we do not know how `MAP` is declared and it is possible that there are mistakes there. And it is, I suppose, possible that the second and third arguments could be arrays. Only you can know those details.

The p/invoke declaration is more verbose than necessary. Were it me I would write it like so:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll")]
public static extern short ReadPx(string filePath, ref MAP Map, ref int numE);
```

In your question you go on to state that you call the function like this:

```
string path = "C:/Users/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/testWrapper2/Map\0";
System.Int16 Output = ReadPx(ref path, ref pix, ref num);
```

The explicit null-terminator that you added is pointless. The framework ensures that the marshalled string has a null-terminator. It doesn't hurt that you add one explicitly, but it serves no purpose. Remove it.

A bigger problem is how you pass the string parameter. The code says:

```
ref path
```

Well, that will not compile because your p/invoke declares the first parameter as a value parameter, as indeed it should.

Clearly then the information presented in the question is erroneous. Perhaps your p/invoke declaration mistakenly declares the first parameter as a `ref` parameter, in contradiction to what is stated in your question.

In summary, given the information that we have, the p/invoke declaration that you provide in the question is accurate. Your actual code is not using that declaration, and instead is using an erroneous declaration.

Comment: Yes, the ref parameter in my actual code was a typo. The real problem was the my second parameter which should be declared with the initial values first. Thanks.